# How to Find Missing Number on Integer Array of 1 to 100?

Tags: java

Here is what i did. What can i do further? Can anybody suggest? I am looking for bitset solution.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

// one missing number
printMissingNumber(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, 6);

// two missing number
printMissingNumber(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10}, 10);

// three missing number
printMissingNumber(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 8}, 10);

// four missing number
printMissingNumber(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8}, 10);

 // Only one missing number in array
int[] iArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 5};
int missing = getMissingNumber(iArray, 5);
System.out.printf("Missing number in array %s is %d %n", 
Arrays.toString(iArray), missing);
```

}

Comment: Where's your implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For n sequential numbers, the sum s = n(n+1)/2.

Sum up the numbers in the array and subtract it from s to find the missing number.

Comment: Plus one, exactly my answer and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is the largest number, and there is only one missing, then the missing number is

```
n * (n + 1) / 2 - sum{elements in your array}
```

The first term is the sum of `n` consecutive integers from 1 to, and including, `n`.

Comment: He was asking about the bitset solution

Comment: Which is a terrible idea.

Comment: terrible is a little strong :)

Comment: Yes, you have a point. There does exist an O(log N) solution, whereas mine is O(N) due to the array sum. So my answer is not as impeccable as I originally thought.